# Possible to convert string to integer with having a word in each string python

Tags: python

```
def oneAction(self):
        coinsaccepted = ("insert 50","insert 25","insert 10","insert 5")
        selectlist = ("select 1","select 2","select 3","select 4","select 5")
        print("Product List: all 35 cents, except bouillon (25 cents)")
        print("1=black,2=white,3=sweet,4=white & sweet, 5=boullion")
        print("Sample commands: insert 25, select 1")
        x = input("Your command : ")
        if x == "quit":
            return False
        elif x in coinsaccepted:
            return True
        elif x in selectlist:
            return True
        elif x  == "cancel":
            print("Returning x cents")
        elif x not in coinsaccepted:
            print("We only take half-dollars, quarters, dimes, and nickels. Coin(s) returned.")
        elif int(x) <= 0:
            print("Invalid Command")
        else:
            print("Invalid Command")
```

So the issue here is that my program needs to take in the input of not just a integer, i need the input of a string as well.

For example, the program will print out insert 50, insert 25, select 1, or select 2.

The input is going to be not just 25, or 50, or 1, or 2. The input is going to be insert 50, or select 1, etc.

I have my program set up to just take it in as a string. However, i need the numbers after the insert, and after the select, to be returned.

Can i convert strings like "insert 50" into integers? I would just need the integer to just be 50 in that case.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You may want to try regex: `int(re.search("\d+", "insert 50").group(0))`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to parse the input. You can do that pretty simply with `.split`, available on strings.

```py
x = input("Your command : ")
command, value = x.split(' ')
value = int(value)

print(command, value)
```

If you provide `insert 25` as input, `command` will equal `'insert'` and `value` will contain `25` (as an `int`).

`.split` takes a string and breaks it into multiple strings that are separated by the provided substring (in this case, a single space). On the left hand side of the equals sign, we have two variables: these pull from the first and second values returned by our split operation.

Note that this will error if you provide a value with more (e.g., `insert 25 cents`) or fewer (e.g., `insert`) words. If the second word is not parseable as an `int`, it will also raise a `ValueError`. You can handle these cases by explicitly testing the length of the output of `.split(' ')` and catching a `ValueError` exception when parsing the `int`.

Answer (score 0):

use python's [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) method to split parts of input and convert as:

```
a = "insert 25"
query,value = a.split(' ')
value = int(value)
```

Here, a string will be split using space as delimiter

Answer (score 0):

```
elif x in coinsaccepted:
    res = x.split()
    string = res[0]
    integer = int(res[1])
```

**Example :** Split the string "insert 50" - ["insert", "50"]

Change string to int.

Comment: An extra space in input would break this logic! Just an information.